# How to receive gmail using imap in server?

Tags: php, email, gmail-imap

I want to receive the mails from gmail using imap. I have used the code `$connection_result = $imap->connect('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx');`
It works in the local xampp but if host in my server, its giving error as

> Cannot connect to Mail: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Network is unreachable

How to use in server. Anyone can help?

Comment: [Do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: I already have that issue. anyone help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'example@gmail.com';
$password = 'example';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails) {
     $output = '';
     rsort($emails);
     foreach($emails as $email_number) {
      $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
       $output.= 'Name:  '.$overview[0]->from.'</br>';
       $output.= 'Message ID:  '.$overview[0]->message_id.'</br>';
       $output.= 'Subject:  '.$overview[0]->subject.'</br>';
       $output.= 'UID:  '.$overview[0]->uid.'</br>';
       $output.= '<hr/>';
     }
      echo $output;
  }  
  imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: Still getting error like "Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Network is unreachable".

Comment: @GowriShankar Give you permission from gmail account

Comment: It wasn't working for me. I worked it out with GMAIL API then. P:)

Comment: I already have that issue. anyone help me please. I've allowed access for less secure apps on the Gmail account and tried https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. But i am getting "Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: Network is unreachable" error.
Also use  $hostname= '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';  but not worked. Please help me.

Comment: $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'my_email_address', 'password_of_gmail') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

Comment: PHP version 7.4